# A straight line is fit to a data set (ln x, y). This line intercepts the abscissa at ln x = 0.1 and with slope of −0.02. Find the value of y at x = 5?

Tags: numerical-methods, analytic-geometry

A straight line is fit to a data set $(ln x, y)$. This line intercepts the abscissa at $ln x = 0.1$ and has a slope of $−0.02$. What is the value of $y$ at $x = 5$ from the fit?

I can not understand what is asking in this problem .

Can anyone please help me to understand?

Comment: For clarity, let's set $t=\ln{x}$. So we assume $y=y(t)$ and that it's a linear relationship, $y=at+b$. We also know that it crosses the abscissa at $t=0.1$, in other words $y(t=0.1) = 0$ or $a\times 0.1 + b = 0$. So we have one equation for the coefficients $a$ and $b$. How would you form the second equation?

Answer (score 0):

y and lnx have a linear relationship.

Let lnx=t then y=y(t).Therefore y=mt+c———>1

Given that the line has an x intercept at lnx=0.1(y=0).

Using 1,
$$0=m(0.1)+c$$
Implies,
$$c=-0.1m——->2$$.

Given that the slope is -0.02 which means that m=-0.02.

From 2,
$$c=-0.1(-0.02)$$
$$c=0.002$$

Therefore the line equation has to be

$$y=-0.02t+0.002$$
i.e,

$$y=-0.02lnx+0.002$$

Therefore when x=5

$$y=-0.02ln5+0.002$$

> $$y\approx-0.0301$$